# Feeds for more specific categories than "recent items"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, feed

By subscribing to the standard "recent feeds", my feed reader gets pounded by questions often duplicates. It would be great if we were able to subscribe to feeds based on following categories,

- Weekly Top
- Monthly top
- Unanswered

... you get the point.
Also how do I get feeds where questions show up only once and not every time it gets answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are now **tab-specific** feeds on the homepage, and when viewing questions by tag.

I think this addresses (most) of your request.

Answer (score 2):

You can already subscribe to any user's feed.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/22164 <-- My personal user feed if you are obsessed like I am with ponies.

Comment: -1 for posting a link to pony related content...

Comment: I hope you incur the wrath of my pony-loving cult following.